# Can we use GetEnumerator() without using IEnumerable interface?

Tags: c#, ienumerator

I have a class called Primes and this class implements GetEnumerator() without implementing IEnumerable interface.

```
public class Primes
{
    private long min;
    private long max;

    public Primes()
        : this(2, 100)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {...}
```

I don't get it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, as others have said you can introduce your own methods without implementing interfaces anyway - you can write your own `Dispose` method without implementing `IDisposable` etc. For well-known interfaces I'd suggest this is almost a bad idea (as readers will have certain expectations) but it's entirely valid.

More importantly though, the `foreach` statement in C# *can* work without `IEnumerable` being involved. The compiler effectively does compile-time duck typing on the names `GetEnumerator()`, `Current` and `MoveNext()`. This was primarily to allow strongly-typed (and non-boxing) iteration in C# 1, before generics. See section 8.8.4 of the C# 3 spec for more details.

However, it's generally a bad idea to do this now if you *do* want to be able to easily iterate over the contents of an instance as a collection - and indeed I'd suggest implementing `IEnumerable<T>` instead of just `IEnumerable`.

Comment: It might actually be a *good** idea to skip the interfaces - if your enumerator is a `struct`. By implementing the interfaces, you will allow the developer to unintentionally introduce boxing of your enumerator wherever it is referenced as `IEnumerable<T>` which is often the case, e.g. in `LINQ`.

Comment: @l33t: I would *at least* have a method that returns an `IEnumerable<T>` so that users who want convenience but don't mind the boxing penalty are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can. even you can use it in `foreach`. The only problem that objects of this class can't be cast to `IEnumerable` although they implement needed method.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason that you have to implement `IEnumerable` in order to create a function called `GetEnumerator` that returns an `IEnumerator`, that just means that you won't be able to supply an instance of that type to something that expects an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

an interface ensures a contract, that does not mean that you can't have a method with the same signature as one in the interface on a class that does not impliment the interface.