# Why this class doesn't need to implement IEnumerable?

Tags: c#

For a class to be able to be iterated using "***foreach***", it should implement the ***IEnumerable*** interface.
but why this simple class with no implementation can be iterated?

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Person() { }
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
    {
        Age = age;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name: {0} {1}, Age: {2}",
        FirstName, LastName, Age);
    }
}
```

when I run the code I get no *error* regarding using **Foreach**

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UseGenericList();
    }

    static void UseGenericList()
    {
        List<Person> people=new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person("Homer","Simpson",47),
            new Person {FirstName = "Marge",LastName ="Simpson",Age = 45},
            new Person {FirstName = "Lisa",LastName = "Simpson",Age = 9},
            new Person {FirstName = "Bart",LastName = "Simpson",Age = 8}
        };
        Console.WriteLine("Items in the list:{0}",people.Count);
        foreach (Person P in people)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(P);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Inserting new person");
        people.Insert(2,new Person {FirstName ="Maggie",LastName = "Simpson",Age = 2});
        Console.WriteLine("items in the list{0}",people.Count);
        Person[] ArraysOfPeople = people.ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < ArraysOfPeople.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First Name:{0}",ArraysOfPeople[i].FirstName);
        }
    }

}
```

why?

Comment: Because you are iterating `List<Person>` you are **not** iterating `Person`. Iterating person would look like `foreach(var something in personObject)` and of course it would fail

Comment: List<T> implement IEnumerable

Answer (score 8):

You are using `List<T>` class for storing your `Person` Collection, where `T` is `Person` class. The `List<T>` class implements `IEnumerable` interface. Hence you are able to use foreach on it

Answer (score 4):

First of all, Abhishek's answer is completely correct; you are working with a `List<T>` *which is an* `IEnumerable`.

---

However, **even if it was not an** `IEnumerable`, it would still work.

[I refer to this SO answer which goes more in depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905737/can-we-use-getenumerator-without-using-ienumerable-interface)

The important bit:

> More importantly though, the `foreach` statement in C# can work without IEnumerable being involved. The compiler effectively does compile-time duck typing on the names `GetEnumerator()`, `Current` and `MoveNext()`. This was primarily to allow strongly-typed (and non-boxing) iteration in C# 1, before generics. See section 8.8.4 of the C# 3 spec for more details.

In other words, it is not required to implement `IEnumerable`, as long as the class provides the necessary methods!

It is of course still highly suggested to simply implement`IEnumerable`, but it is not technically required.

Answer (score -1):

To clarify more, the statement you are using i.e.

```
foreach (Person P in people)
{
    Console.WriteLine(P);
}
```

people here is List of person i.e. List and your List implements IEnumerable which has a method named [GetEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Initially, the enumerator is positioned before the first element in
>   the collection. The Reset method also brings the enumerator back to
>   this position. At this position, the Current property is undefined.
>   Therefore, you must call the MoveNext method to advance the enumerator
>   to the first element of the collection before reading the value of
>   Current.
>
> Current returns the same object until either MoveNext or
>   Reset is called. MoveNext sets Current to the next element.
>
> If MoveNext passes the end of the collection, the enumerator is
>   positioned after the last element in the collection and MoveNext
>   returns false. When the enumerator is at this position, subsequent
>   calls to MoveNext also return false. If the last call to MoveNext
>   returns false, Current is undefined. To set Current to the first
>   element of the collection again, you can call Reset followed by
>   MoveNext.

For more unconventional indirect learning refer to [Eric's Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern/)

> You might think that in order to use a foreach loop, the collection
>   you are iterating over must implement `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`.
>   But as it turns out, that is not actually a requirement. What is
>   required is that the type of the collection must have a public method
>   called GetEnumerator, and that must return some type that has a public
>   property getter called Current and a public method MoveNext that
>   returns a bool. If the compiler can determine that all of those
>   requirements are met then the code is generated to use those methods.
>   Only if those requirements are not met do we check to see if the
>   object implements IEnumerable or IEnumerable.

Comment: I think the naming is ok..."people" is the plural of "person".